# Copy only the entered character from one text box to another

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two text box `#textBox1` and `#textBox2`.

User will input to `#textBox1` and all the values need to be copied to `#textBox2` automatically [I have a `onkeyup` event here]. Only copy and paste from one to another is not a problem. My requirement is once user press `space` or `enter` my English word from `#textBox1`  will convert to local language but I need only the English version on `#textBox2`.

See the example below:

`textBox1 = "Bhuwan", textBox2="Bhuwan"`

once user press space bar

```
textBox1 = "भुवन ", textBox2="Bhuwan "

textBox1 = "भुवन Gautam", textBox2="Bhuwan Gautam"
```

Again once user press space bar

```
textBox1 = "भुवन गौतम", textBox2="Bhuwan Gautam"
```

I have used the following but it is not complete if the user use backspace on `#textBox1`.

```
$("#textBox1").keyup(function(e) {
            $('#textBox2').val($('#textBox2').val()+String.fromCharCode(e.which));
});
```

I know there is a better solution. How do I achieve this either from jquery or javascript ?

Comment: waht you researched on this ???

Comment: I have updated my answer what I have come up with.

Comment: can you provide fiddle for your code

Comment: FYI, I am using transliteration on my textBox1.

Answer (score 2):

I think You can go through this solution [Click](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5388330/5336818)

I will highlight some points.

Use Google translation API. Easy to use. For example the following translates Spanish to English. To translate from and to other languages, simply change 'es' and 'en'

```
google.load("language", "1");

function initialize() {
    var content = document.getElementById('content');
    content.innerHTML = '<div id="text">Hola, me alegro mucho de verte.<\/div><div id="translation"/>';
    var text = document.getElementById("text").innerHTML;
    google.language.translate(text, 'es', 'en', function(result) {
        var translated = document.getElementById("translation");
        if (result.translation) {
            translated.innerHTML = result.translation;
        }
    });
}
google.setOnLoadCallback(initialize);
```

try **google translate**: http://code.google.com/apis/language/translate/overview.html

You can also use this **JQuery plugin** http://www.openxrest.com/translatejs

You can use **bing translate** .. http://setahost.com/bing-translate-api-with-jquery-ajax/ Bing api is still free

Comment: @BhuwanGautam :You mean you tried all the solutions ?? there are three solutions :P

Comment: Hmm..tried the first one. Third one link did not work. Second option look promising. Will give a try.

Comment: unfortunately translate.js does not have support for Nepali language.