# How to translate text generated with javascript

Tags: javascript, php, adminlte

So adminlte has the trans() function which works perfectly when its used in blade.php.

Lets say i have a form that if completed incorrectly throws a warning. I do the checking in js. And I want to have a pop up message that is displayed. The message need to be translatable.

What I tried is - in the php file make an array with the translatable text:

```
    $returnArr = [
        'titleSuccess' => trans('title.success'),
        'titleWarning' => trans('title.warning')
    ];
```

Then retrieve it in the js and display the message.

```
    $.post('/' + currentLanguage.locale + '/admin/page/error', {id:sId, note:note})
    .done(function (result) {

        if (result.status === 1) {
            msg
                .html(createAlert(result.titleSuccess, result.msg, 'success'))
                .slideDown('fast');


        } else {
            msg
                .html(createAlert(result.titleError, result.msg, 'danger'))
                .slideDown('fast');
        }
    })
```

The problem is these keywords- title.warning, title.success are translated but in the default language that is set in the system. Not the one that the user has set.

Why is that happening? And is there a way to use trans() in js?

Comment: You can use `Google Translate API`.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/5388330/3565182