# How can translate alert box text , Google Translate Translate my website perfectly but Not Show Translated Language In Alert Message box web

Tags: javascript, html, google-translate

I have added google translate in my web site which is work perfactly but in my web i have use alert message so the google translator is not translate alert message text

see demo below

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-fr" xml:lang="en-fr" xmlns= "http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="google" content="notranslate">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Language" content="en-fr">
<body>

<h1>My Web Page</h1>

<p>Hello everybody!</p>

<p>Translate this page:</p>

<div id="google_translate_element"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
function googleTranslateElementInit() {
  new google.translate.TranslateElement({pageLanguage: 'en-fr'}, 'google_translate_element');
}
function showMessage(){
alert('show translated language');
}
</script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="//translate.google.com/translate_a/element.js?cb=googleTranslateElementInit"></script>

<p>You can translate the content of this page by selecting a language in the select box.</p>
<button onclick="showMessage()">Show</button>
</body>
</html>
```

please help me what should i do for this

if required more clarification or detail just comment here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do it is this

Have a `<span>` tag with a display of none, and put inside of it 'show translated language'. Then in your function `showMessage()` fetch the innerHTML of that span. It would look like this:

HTML

```
<span id='text' style="display: none;">show translated language</span>
```

JS

```
function showMessage() {
  alert(text.innerHTML)
}
```

Retrospectively, I just wanted to add this link to anyone who is experiencing the same problem. While my method will work, it is somewhat of a dirty practice and shouldn't be done too often. The 'cleanest' way of solving this problem is to import a js plugin like `translate.js`. The implementation of this plugin and examples is given in this post [JavaScript/jQuery - Get text and translate it](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5388127/11342997)

Comment: thank you soo much, this is very good idea,
can you help me more because currently i have one large web site already live, so this is very very large change to my website so have any idea about how can make it dynamically

Comment: What do you mean by 'dynamically'. Do you mean it would be really hard to manually change because your current website is really big?

Comment: Yes , current website we use too many alert box(around 1000+) so it is very very different to change it manually at all

Comment: i appreciate your answer thanks, if found any solution then please comment here